# Thread synchronization necessity on a `volatile __shared__` flag

Tags: cuda, synchronization, gpu-shared-memory

My questions arise while reading the last example of [B.5. Memory Fence Functions](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#memory-fence-functions).
I understand the flag in this example checks the final block processing a sum.

In my imagination, if the flag is declared as `volatile __shared__` and without the usage of `__syncthreads()`, the threads could see the flag `true` sooner or later, more likely not at the same time to see the flag with `true`.

So I start to think **if I could do the same thing without the `__syncthreads()`?** Do we have any alternative replacement or workaround, in the case when we have a volatile shared memory flag?

(I gave my dummy designs in the following part, where they are both not working.)

---

Try 1:

```cpp
__device__ unsigned int count = 0;
volatile __shared__ bool isLastBlockDone;   /// as volatile
__global__ void sum(const float* array, unsigned int N,
                    volatile float* result)
{
    float partialSum = calculatePartialSum(array, N);
    if (threadIdx.x == 0) {
        result[blockIdx.x] = partialSum;
        __threadfence();
        unsigned int value = atomicInc(&count, gridDim.x);
        isLastBlockDone = (value == (gridDim.x - 1));
    }

    while (!isLastBlockDone) __threadfence_block();   /// No __syncthreads();

    if (isLastBlockDone) {
        float totalSum = calculateTotalSum(result);
        if (threadIdx.x == 0) {
            result[0] = totalSum;
            count = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

The motivation is to use a busy waiting loop to find the moment when the flag `isLastBlockDone` is true. However, this code didn't work with more than 1 block in the launch configuration. I strongly believe the Thread Divergence is happening here. So, is the `__syncthreads();` the only necessary way there to make it work?

Try 2:

```cpp
__global__ void sum(const float* array, unsigned int N,
                    volatile float* result)
{
    volatile __shared__ unsigned int count;      /// as __shared__
    volatile __shared__ bool isLastThreadDone;   /// as volatile
    count = 0;
    isLastThreadDone = false;
    __syncthreads();                             /// Init

    float partialSum = calculatePartialSum(array, N);
    result[blockIdx.x] = partialSum;
    __threadfence();
    unsigned int value = atomicInc(&count, blockDim.x);
    isLastThreadDone = (value == (blockDim.x - 1));
    
    while (!isLastThreadDone) __threadfence_block();   /// No __syncthreads();

    if (isLastThreadDone) {
        float totalSum = calculateTotalSum(result);
        if (threadIdx.x == 0) {
            result[0] = totalSum;
            count = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

The motivation there is to migrate the original example from checking the last block to **checking the last thread in each block**. The reason I came to this motivation, is that I prefer the `volatile __shared__ bool` would be better to only bookkeep inside a block, so I let `count` and `isLastThreadDone` to be block-local `__shared__`.

However, the issue remains, that the program still has a deadlock. Again, I guess that the Thread Divergence is happening here. So, is the `__syncthreads();` the only way there to make it work?

---

In addition, I make the examples above to address the thread synchronization and let the program be terminated without any deadlock. The correctness of the summing is not the main focus of my questions.

Answer (score 3):

In some cases, it should be possible to replace a `__syncthreads()` statement with a shared memory spin-wait, however I question the utility of it. First of all I have no data that suggests that it is more efficient/faster/better, and secondly I don't think it obviates the need to have `__syncthreads()` in the code *somewhere*, it just pushes the need for the statement somewhere else (and, thirdly, as indicated below, it trips the `racecheck` tool).

Your `try1` case doesn't make sense, because the general strategy there is part of a threadblock-draining reduction (refer to `threadFenceReduction` sample code).  The threadblock-draining mechanism uses atomics to signal which threadblock is the last to reach the "end".  Only one threadblock will get this signal; all others simply exit.  Therefore, since only one threadblock will receive a boolean `true` condition for `isLastBlockDone`, all other threadblocks, which would normally just exit, are left spin-waiting forever at the subsequent `while` statement.  You have predictable deadlock.  It has nothing to do with thread divergence.  *All* threads, in all threadblocks, will behave identically at the `while` statement, but the condition needed to exit that `while` loop is only satisfied for one threadblock.

Your `try2` example is simpler to indict.  Since you have converted all usage to `__shared__` memory, there could not possibly be any inter-threadblock communication with this approach, so it is completely unsuited to coordinating the behavior of multiple threadblocks.

To come up with anything resembling your request, we will need to combine elements from both approaches:

- retain the atomic mechanism to communicate among threadblocks
- replace the `__syncthreads()` *at that point* with an equivalent spin-wait.

The basic (1D) threadblock-draining approach looks like this:

```
__device__ int count = 0;
....
__shared__ bool i_am_last_block;
perform_threadblock_level_reduction();
if (!threadIdx.x){
  int value = atomicAdd(&count, 1);
  i_am_last_block = (value == (gridDim.x - 1));}
__syncthreads();  // **
if (i_am_last_block)
  perform_final_stage_reduction();
```

If you really want to for some reason, it should be possible to replace (or, at least, *move*) the `__syncthreads()` statement above delineated with `// **`, by using a spin-wait instead:

```
__device__ int count = 0;
....
__shared__ volatile bool ready;
__shared__ volatile bool i_am_last_block;
if (!threadIdx.x) ready = false;
__syncthreads();
perform_threadblock_level_reduction();
if (!threadIdx.x){
  int value = atomicAdd(&count, 1);
  i_am_last_block = (value == (gridDim.x - 1));
  ready = true;}
while (!ready);  
if (i_am_last_block)
  perform_final_stage_reduction();
```

Note that the `__syncthreads()` statement has "moved" from the end of the thread code to the beginning.  However, any `__syncthreads()` usage between the initialization of `ready` and its usage by thread 0 in the `if` statement will satisfy the need; it may not be strictly necessary to explicitly add another `__syncthreads()` statement.  Stated another way, any sensible `perform_threadblock_level_reduction()` that I am familiar with that produces a single partial sum for the threadblock, would necessarily involve `__syncthreads()` usage.  Therefore, with that proviso, the "extra" `__syncthreads()` that I have depicted would not be necessary.

I consider all this unlikely to produce useful results in terms of code performance.  Here is a complete example:

```
$ cat t1942.cu
#include <iostream>

const int nTPB = 256;  // must be power-of-2
template <typename T>
__device__ void perform_threadblock_level_reduction(T *in, T *out, size_t n, size_t oidx, size_t start, size_t stride){
  __shared__ T sdata[nTPB];
  sdata[threadIdx.x] = 0;
  for (size_t i = start; i < n; i += stride) sdata[threadIdx.x] += in[i];
  for (int i = nTPB>>1; i > 0; i >>= 1){
    __syncthreads();
    if (threadIdx.x < i) sdata[threadIdx.x] += sdata[threadIdx.x+i];}
  if (!threadIdx.x) {out[oidx] = sdata[0];  __threadfence();}
}

__device__ int count = 0;
template <typename T>
__global__ void r(T *in, T *out, size_t n){
  __shared__ volatile bool ready;
  __shared__ volatile bool i_am_last_block;
  if (!threadIdx.x) ready = false;
  perform_threadblock_level_reduction(in, out, n, blockIdx.x, blockIdx.x*blockDim.x+threadIdx.x, gridDim.x*blockDim.x);
  if (!threadIdx.x){
    int value = atomicAdd(&count, 1);
    i_am_last_block = (value == (gridDim.x - 1));
    ready = true;}
  while (!ready);
  if (i_am_last_block)
    perform_threadblock_level_reduction(out, out, gridDim.x, 0, threadIdx.x, blockDim.x);
}

typedef int mt;
const size_t s = 1048576;
const int nBLK = 64;
int main(){

  mt *in, *out;
  cudaMallocManaged(&in, s*sizeof(mt));
  cudaMallocManaged(&out, nBLK*sizeof(mt));
  for (size_t i = 0; i < s; i++) in[i] = 1;
  r<<<nBLK, nTPB>>>(in, out, s);
  cudaDeviceSynchronize();
  std::cout << out[0] << std::endl;
}
$ nvcc -o t1942 t1942.cu -lineinfo
$ compute-sanitizer ./t1942
========= COMPUTE-SANITIZER
1048576
========= ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors
$
```

Note that the `cuda-memcheck` or `compute-sanitizer` tool `racecheck` will report errors in the above cases. This is due to the fact that there is inter-thread communication using shared variables, with no intervening `__syncthreads()` statement (basically, your request).  However the `while` loop plus usage of `volatile` makes the code work anyway.

There is an additional challenge or drawback to this method of replacing a `__syncthreads()` with a spin-wait.  When warps fully arrive at a `__syncthreads()`, while waiting at the `__syncthreads()`, they are [stalled](https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/cuda-7-5-pinpoint-performance-problems-instruction-level-profiling/).  This is important because it means the warp scheduler cannot select those warps for scheduling/issue.  As warps successively arrive at a `__syncthreads()`, then the scheduler attention is "focused" on the remaining warps.  This gives a useful forward-progress impetus to those warps, effectively ensuring that the `__syncthreads()` will eventually be satisfied, if possible.

The spin-wait method has no such advantage.  Warps "waiting" at the spin-wait are still schedulable.  And while it seems unlikely to occur in practice, it is at least theoretically possible that the warp scheduler could "always" select warps that are at the spin-wait, over warps that still need to make forward progress.  (At least, we can say it is not a trivial matter to rule this possibility out.)  The effect of this would be a deadlock.  Therefore, the use of `__syncthreads()` has clear advantages over spin-wait, even if spin-wait "seems" workable.